# Any strategies or tips on how to make juice into creams for filling cakes?

Tags: cream, pastry, filling

So Custard powder and Custard are both expensive where I am from. My mom is looking for ways to do creams to put inside pastries.
Currently, what I do is use Fresh Milk, melted butter and some flavoring. 
Will adding gelatin to water and juice make them look and taste like fillings?
I am thinking of using purple yams as flavor, like a jam, and then make them creamier by adding them to the butter and hot milk.
Any tips will receive digital hugs XD
But really, thanks. hopefully, it is not expensive XD

Comment: If you have eggs and milk, you can make custard the [traditional way](https://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/classic-custard) - change, add or leave the flavorings as needed.

Comment: Just look up a recipe for pastry cream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many thickeners that can make fruit juices into thick fillings.

You can make a traditional egg custard, as bob1's reply to your answer mentions.

You can make a non-egg filling using other thickeners, like gelatin or starches. Popular starch thickeners to use for pastry fillings are corn starch and tapioca powder. Any of these will work well with liquid flavoring ingredients like fruit juice. Corn starch is very cheap, at least here in the U.S.

Yams already contain a lot of starch and very little liquid, so you will need to add liquid (milk or cream should work well) if you plan on using additional thickeners (which may help achieve a smoother, less chalky texture). I do not recommend gelatin for yam filling because I don't believe the textures will go well together.

"Yam" is a word that is applied to a bunch of different roots, but I think it's worth looking at this [Portuguese Trutas recipe](https://www.injennieskitchen.com/2009/08/trutas-a-portuguese-treat/). These sweet potato pastries are amazing and don't require additional thickeners. Note that the yam or potato should be pureed, not mashed.

Comment: Thanks a lot JQTaylor! So would you happen to know at least a general overview regarding ratio? I can use rice flour or rice starch here (Asia) 
If I say use mango juice 1 cup, do I add a tablespoon of gelatin? How about durain and what not?
I realyl appreciate it!

Comment: The gelatin container is the best place to find instructions about a liquid ratio. Try this recipe for a starch solution (use twice as much rice starch as corn starch in corn starch recipes). https://veenaazmanov.com/eggless-vanilla-pastry-cream/ If you're not using a recipe, remember, the water content must be enough to saturate the combined starch and/or gelatin content. Don't worry as much about balancing the sugar and fat content.